# Semantic-Ui pointing menu sub menu items rendered with the "point"

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am writing an application using semantic-ui for the frontend.  I have a pointing menu with a dropdown menu item.  The items in the dropdown menu are rendered with the point between the elements of the dropwdown menu.

Is there a way to solve this?

Code:

```
<div class="ui attached inverted pointing menu">
  <a class="ui item">
    <div class="ui transparent inverted labeled icon fluid input">
      <div class="ui inverted black pointing dropdown label">
        <div class="text">Menu Item</div>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu>
          <div class="item">Menu Item<div>
          <div class="item">Menu Item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input id="search" type="text">
      <i class="inverted search link icon"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Help appreciated.  Thank you!